# Laravel eloquent: search by tags with orderBy on found tags number

Tags: search, tags, eloquent

**Hi!**

I have a relationship: ManyToMany between tags and snippets (through a pivot table: snippet_tag).

I want to make a search by tags on snippets list. The issue is, how to order the search results by the number of found tags.

Here is my code:

```
        $tags = explode(" ", $tags);
        $snippets = Snippet::whereHas('tags', function ($q) use ($tags, $tags_db_table) {
            $q->WhereIn($tags_db_table.'.name', $tags);
        })->paginate(10);
```

**In the example below, I have 4 tags which gave 5 results:**

*1st snippet: 1 tag found (green tags)*

*2nd snippet: 3 tags found (green tags)*

*3rd snippet: 2 tags found (green tags)*

*4th snippet: 2 tags found (green tags)*

*5th snippet: 2 tags found (green tags)*

**How to make 2nd snippet appear first (3 tags found) and 1st result appears last (1 tag found)**

**Thanks!**

[image]

[Search by tags with eloquent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWbjY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it! Here is the answer if you have the same issue as me.
If you have any optimization i'll be glad to know.
Thanks

```html
<?php

      $snippets = \DB::table('tags as t')
                  ->join('snippet_tag', 't.id', '=', 'snippet_tag.tag_id')
                  ->leftJoin('snippets as s', 's.id', '=', 'snippet_tag.snippet_id')
                  ->WhereIn('t.name', $tags)
                  ->select(['s.id', 's.title', \DB::raw('COUNT(og_t.id) AS  found_tags_number')])
                  ->groupBy('s.id')
                  ->orderBy('found_tags_number', 'DESC')
                  ->paginate(10);

      foreach ($snippets as $k => $snippet) {
          $snippets[$k]->tags = \DB::table('tags')
                                    ->join('snippet_tag', 'tags.id', '=', 'snippet_tag.tag_id')
                                    ->where('snippet_tag.snippet_id', '=', $snippets[$k]->id)
                                    ->select('name')
                                    ->get();
      }
```